# c++ random number between two integers using WELL512

Tags: c++, random, generator

I see that this question *may* have been answered here: [Random using WELL512](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785113/getting-a-random-real-number-in-a-certain-range-using-well512/)

However, it's not quite user friendly and doesn't provide an example how to use it in a 'real world' piece of code.

Here is what I currently have:

```
#define m (unsigned long)2147483647
#define q (unsigned long)127773    
#define a (unsigned int)16807
#define r (unsigned int)2836    

static unsigned long seed;    
void x_srandom(unsigned long initial_seed);
unsigned long x_random(void);    

void x_srandom(unsigned long initial_seed)
{
    seed = initial_seed;
}    

unsigned long x_random(void)
{
    int lo, hi, test;

    hi = (seed / q);
    lo = (seed % q);

    test = (a * lo - r * hi);

    if (test > 0)
        seed = test;
    else
        seed = (test + m);

    return (seed);
}

int RANDOM(int from, int to)
{
    if (from > to)
    {
        int tmp = from;
        from = to;
        to = tmp;
    }
    return ((x_random() % (to - from + 1)) + from);
}

// Real world function using RANDOM()
void testFunction()
{
    printf("A random number between 1 and 1000 is %d \r\n", RANDOM(1, 1000));
    printf("A random number between 36 and 100 is %d \r\n", RANDOM(36, 100));
    printf("A random number between 1 and 2147483647 is %d \r\n", RANDOM(1, 2147483647));
    printf("A random number between 1 and 5 is %d \r\n", RANDOM(1, 5));
}
```

The above example shows everything you need to know to implement it.

I would like to use WELL512 to determine my random numbers instead of the way in which I currently am, put in a way as exampled above.

Comment: Using modulo with anything but a power of two (like, 1000 or 36) will give a biased distribution. You should avoid doing that.

Answer (score 3):

It is really time to move away from using % for generating a distribution.

To me you should use WELL512 as a uniform random number generator (just like mt19937 in the standard library). You wrap it in a class that exposes a typedef (or using) for result_type. In your case that would probably be unsigned long. Then you need two constexpr for min() and max(). That would be 0 and ULONG_MAX. Finally you need to expose operator() that returns a single unsigned long.

After that you use the features in `<random>` together with your engine.

```
class well512 {
public:
    typedef unsigned long result_type;
    static constexpr result_type min() { return 0; }
    static constexpr result_type max() { return ULONG_MAX; }
    result_type operator()() { /* return some value from the underlying well512 implementation */ }
};

int main()
{
    well512 engine();
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist { 1, 5 };

    for (int i = 0; i != 10; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << dist(engine) << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete example. It does not have all the bells and whistles you may want. E.g. there is no default constructor, or a constructor from a single word. I leave that as an exercise.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <limits>
#include <numeric>
#include <ostream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

class seed_seq
{
public:
    template <typename InputIterator>
    seed_seq(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)
    {
        for (; first != last; ++first)
        {
            v.push_back(*first);
        }
    }

    template <typename RandomAccessIterator>
    void generate(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last)
    {
        std::vector<unsigned int>::size_type i = 0;
        for (; first != last; ++first)
        {
            *first = v[i];
            if (++i == v.size()){ i = 0; }
        }
    }

private:
    std::vector<unsigned int> v;
};

class well512
{
public:
    using result_type = unsigned int;

    static result_type min() { return 0; }
    static result_type max() { return std::numeric_limits<std::uint32_t>::max(); }

    static const unsigned int state_size = 16;

    explicit well512(seed_seq& sequence) : index(0)
    { sequence.generate(std::begin(state), std::end(state)); }

    result_type operator()()
    {
        std::uint32_t z0 = state[(index + 15) & 0x0fU];
        std::uint32_t z1 = xsl(16, state[index]) ^ xsl(15, state[(index + 13) & 0x0fU]);
        std::uint32_t z2 = xsr(11, state[(index + 9) & 0x0fU]);
        state[index] = z1 ^ z2;
        std::uint32_t t = xslm(5, 0xda442d24U, state[index]);
        index = (index + state_size - 1) & 0x0fU;
        state[index] = xsl(2, z0) ^ xsl(18, z1) ^ (z2 << 28) ^ t;

        return state[index];
    }

private:
    // xor-shift-right
    std::uint32_t xsr(unsigned int shift, std::uint32_t value)
    { return value ^ (value >> shift); }

    // xor-shift-left
    std::uint32_t xsl(unsigned int shift, std::uint32_t value)
    { return value ^ (value << shift); }

    // xor-shift-left and mask
    std::uint32_t xslm(unsigned int shift, std::uint32_t mask, std::uint32_t value)
    { return value ^ ((value << shift) & mask); }

    unsigned int index;
    std::array<std::uint32_t, state_size> state;
};

int main()
{
    // Use a random device to generate 16 random words used as seed for the well512 engine
    std::random_device rd;

    std::vector<well512::result_type> seed_data;
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(seed_data), well512::state_size, std::ref(rd));

    seed_seq sequence(std::begin(seed_data), std::end(seed_data));

    // Create a well512 engine
    well512 engine(sequence);

    // Now apply it like any other random engine in C++11
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist{ 1, 6 };
    auto rand = std::function <int()> { std::bind(std::ref(dist), std::ref(engine)) };

    // Print out some random numbers between 1 and 6 (simulating throwing a dice)
    const int n = 100;
    std::generate_n(std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "), n, rand);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this user515430 ?

```
#define m  (unsigned long)2147483647

#define W 32
#define R 16
#define P 0
#define M1 13
#define M2 9
#define M3 5

#define MAT0POS(t,v) (v^(v>>t))
#define MAT0NEG(t,v) (v^(v<<(-(t))))
#define MAT3NEG(t,v) (v<<(-(t)))
#define MAT4NEG(t,b,v) (v ^ ((v<<(-(t))) & b))

#define V0            STATE[state_i                   ]
#define VM1           STATE[(state_i+M1) & 0x0000000fU]
#define VM2           STATE[(state_i+M2) & 0x0000000fU]
#define VM3           STATE[(state_i+M3) & 0x0000000fU]
#define VRm1          STATE[(state_i+15) & 0x0000000fU]
#define VRm2          STATE[(state_i+14) & 0x0000000fU]
#define newV0         STATE[(state_i+15) & 0x0000000fU]
#define newV1         STATE[state_i                 ]
#define newVRm1       STATE[(state_i+14) & 0x0000000fU]

#define FACT 2.32830643653869628906e-10

static unsigned int state_i = 0;
static unsigned int STATE[R];
static unsigned int z0, z1, z2;

void InitWELLRNG512a(unsigned int *init){
    int j;
    state_i = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < R; j++)
        STATE[j] = init[j];
}

double WELLRNG512a(void){
    z0 = VRm1;
    z1 = MAT0NEG(-16, V0) ^ MAT0NEG(-15, VM1);
    z2 = MAT0POS(11, VM2);
    newV1 = z1                  ^ z2;
    newV0 = MAT0NEG(-2, z0) ^ MAT0NEG(-18, z1) ^ MAT3NEG(-28, z2) ^ MAT4NEG(-5, 0xda442d24U, newV1);
    state_i = (state_i + 15) & 0x0000000fU;
    return ((double)STATE[state_i]) * FACT;
}

int RANDOM(int from, int to)
{
    if (from > to)
    {
        int tmp = from;
        from = to;
        to = tmp;
    }

    return to + (from - to) * (WELLRNG512a() / (long double)m);
}
```

Comment: Nevermind.  This just outputs the largest number every time.  RANDOM(1, 100) always results in 100.  (back to the drawing board)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get a uniformly distributed random integer between two values is with floating point math.

```
double get_uniform_rand() {
    /*Assumes unsigned 32 bit return value from myrnd in range 0 - 0xFFFFFFFF*/
    return (double)myrnd() / (double)0xFFFFFFFF;
}

int32_t get_rnd_in_range(int32_t l, int32_t h) {
    return (int32_t)((double)l + get_uniform_rand() * (double)(h-l));
}
```

This is more of a C approach, as, like user515430 mentioned, there's a standard C++ way of doing this (though I personally have not used it).