# Distinguish zero and negative zero

Tags: c++, floating-point, comparison, zero, negative-number

I have run into a situation in my code where a function returns a double, and it is possible for this double to be a zero, a negative zero, or another value entirely. I need to distinguish between zero and negative zero, but the default double comparison does not. Due to the format of doubles, C++ does not allow for comparison of doubles using bitwise operators, so I am unsure how to procede. How can I distinguish between the two?

Comment: try -0.0 instead of -0

Comment: Why do you need to disambiguate these?

Comment: Hm, not sure if I get the question correctly. You need to compare 2 `double`s? And make difference between the positive/negative value or want to treat them just as `zero`?

Comment: Comparing floating point values for equality is almost always wrong. Why do you need it?

Comment: I assume that a negative 0 is the number with all bits 0, except the sin bit which is 1.  Can you give an example of how you can actually get that number? no arithmetic operations I can think of can lead to this.

Comment: @Pandrei: For example, `1e-300 / -1e300`.

Comment: @n.m. comparing for exact equality is often correct. And negative zero was designed for a specific use case. In order to make use of neg zero, you have to detect it.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier Not a duplicate of that. That other question, as it turned out, wasn't even about negative zero in the first place, it was just a normal negative number that was small enough that with default precision, it looked like negative zero when printed.

Comment: @benjamin This is not a dupe of that Q

Comment: Ups, yes, you are both right.

Answer (score 18):

Call [`std::signbit()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/signbit) to determine the state of the sign bit.

Answer (score 9):

> Due to the format of doubles, C++ does not allow for comparison of doubles using bitwise operators, so I am unsure how to procede.

First off, C++ doesn't mandate any standard for `float`/`double` types.

Assuming you're talking about IEEE 754's *binary32* and *binary64* formats, they're specifically designed to maintain their order when their [bit patterns are interpreted as integers](http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/) so that a non-FPU can sort them; this is the reason they have a biased exponent.

There're [many SO posts](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow.com%20floating%20point%20bitwise%20compare) discussing such comparisons; here's [the most relevant one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2582417/183120). A simple check would be

```
bool is_negative_zero(float val)
{
   return ((val == 0.0f) && std::signbit(val));
}
```

This works since `0.0f == -0.0f`, although there're places where the sign makes a difference like `atan2` or when dividing by -0 as opposed to +0 leads to the respective infinities.

Answer (score -3):

To test explicitly for a == -0 in C do the following:

```
if (*((long *)&a) == 0x8000000000000000) {
    //  a is -0
}
```

Comment: ... if (_and only if_) you know the platform uses IEC 60559 representation in that endianness, and if `long` is the same size as `double` ...